# Angular ui-timepicker - not change the data in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ui, timepicker

In html:

```
<input ng-model="schedule.when" ui-timepicker="timePickerOptions"/>
```

In js - i have this :

```
let toTime = (dStr) => {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setHours(dStr.substr(0, dStr.indexOf(":")));
    now.setMinutes(dStr.substr(dStr.indexOf(":") + 1));
    now.setSeconds(0);
    return now;
}
```

`data.MowingDays[i].when =  moment(toTime(data.MowingDays[i].when));`  // (13:00);

At first i convert the string from json to a moment object . 
 -    [momentjs](https://github.com/moment/moment)

This is the options i put in :

```
$scope.timePickerOptions = {
        step: 20,
        appendTo: 'body',
        timeFormat: 'H:ss' ,
        change: function(data)
        {
                $scope.selectChanged();
                console.log(date); // Sun Dec 31 1899 15:00:00 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time)
                $scope.$apply();

        }
    };
```

when i click on "save" , it need to save the new data. - update the json

The problem is that the "data.MowingDays[i].when" at JSON , not change.

it allways the same:
"2016-11-01T11:00:00.070Z"

the json is :

```
        let scheduleXJSON =
        {
            "MowingDays":
            [{
                "day" : "sun",
                "active": false,
                "when": "13:00",
                "where": "Base(main)",
                "howlong": "Max (Up to 90 Min)"
            },
            {
                "day"   : "mon",
                "active": false,
                "when": "13:00",
                "where": "Base(main)",
                "howlong": "Max (Up to 90 Min)"
            }]
        }
```

Comment: can you post your `toTime` function ?

Comment: @AlexandruMihai Yes . i update.

Comment: How looks your `data.MowingDays` ?

Comment: @AlexandruMihai I add the JSON.